# Проверить наличия элемента в массиве с обрезанием текста

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно проверить массив.

Идея в том чтобы проверить массив на команды, и если команда найдена то следовательно далее пройти по коду, если не найдено то exit();

Ко мне по этому поводу приходит только 1 идея:

```php
<?php

$text = 'Команда1 параметры';
$commands = array(
    'Команда1' => array(...),
    'Команда2' => array(...)
);

foreach($commands as $cmd => $args)
{
    if(mb_substr($text, 0, mb_strlen($cmd)) == $cmd)
    {
        ...
    }

}

?>
```

Но такой вариант слишком долгий, да и не самый Хороший.
Вопрос: можно ли проверить в массиве существует ли команда, и обрезать ее по тексту который присылает пользователь?
( лучше 1 строку, просто не могу найти в интернете как можно и обрезать и найти в 1 строку. )

Просто без mb_substr не получается проверит потому что php проверяет ещё и на кол-во букв ( strlen ).

Почему я не использую explode, все просто: команда может состоять из 2 и более слов.

Comment: ничего не понятно. что обрезать? почему проверить иначе не получается? что делать с командой, нужны ли параметры?

Comment: `$el = explode(' ', $text); if (array_key_exists($el[0], $commands)) { ... }` не используйте команду из 2 и более слов. это неверно т.к. не понятно где команда, а где аргумент

Comment: Я же говорю что команда может состоять из 2 слов, такая идея была, но я от неё отказался